# Set belongs to sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

How to show that the set $\{(x, y) : 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq1, x + y \leq 1\}$ belongs to
the σ-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I know these rules about sigma-algebra

If sigma-algebra F is a nonempty collection of subsets of X such that the following hold:

1. X is in F.
2. If A is in F, then so is the complement of A.
3. If A_n is a sequence of elements of F, then the union of the A_ns is in F.

But not sure how to prove below using these.

Comment: Hi @salve, are you allowed to prove this without using the properties of sigma-algebras?

Comment: Hi @Mangostino! yes, that works as well

Comment: It's my initial guess that we needed these properties

Answer (score 1):

The map $f:[0,1]^2 \to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y) := x+y$ is continuous, hence measurable. Note that
$$ f^{-1}[0,1] = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 : x+y\leqslant 1\}. $$

Comment: Thank you, but how do we know that the map :[0,1]2→ℝ given by (,):=+ is continuous?

Comment: @salve Polynomials are smooth.

Comment: how do you get the −1 then?

Comment: @salve The use of preimage is not dependent on continuity. The argument is that the subset of interest is a preimage of a Borel set under a measurable map. Therefore it has to be a measurable subset.

Comment: but I still don't understand how you go from (,):=+  to +⩽1